# Research on more effective search systems based on Human–computer information retrieval?

Tags: research, hci, hcir

Within the field of User Experience, a lot of interdisciplinary boundaries intersect and co-exist finding new knowledge from different views. One part where results have yet to come (?) is the field of Human–computer information retrieval which aims at making users more in control of the search process:

> [Human–computer information retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human%E2%80%93computer_information_retrieval) (HCIR) is the study of information retrieval techniques that bring human intelligence into the search process. The fields of human–computer interaction (HCI) and information retrieval (IR) have both developed innovative techniques to address the challenge of navigating complex information spaces, but their insights have often failed to cross disciplinary borders. Human–computer information retrieval has emerged in academic research and industry practice to bring together research in the fields of IR and HCI, in order to create new kinds of search systems that depend on continuous human control of the search process.

Still one wonders how far this research area has come in its striving to gain new knowledge. Any reference to a white paper or an scientific article will do for the accepted answer on this question, since my own search attempts have failed so far.  **Is there research on more effective search systems based on Human–computer information retrieval?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this page:

https://sites.google.com/site/hcirworkshop/

The papers from 2012 must be bought (unless you're a member of the ACM) but previos year's papers seem to be freely accessible.  Looks like a good place to start digging.

Comment: +1 Thanxs! This was too close even for my google search strings :-)

Answer (score 0):

If there are they are still based in academia and have not been published and/or revealed. In my 15 years I haven't seen any documentation on HCIR specifics.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/hcirworkshop/ - there's plenty there to buy or if you're a member of the ACM it's free.